# Create object from NSString of class name in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if i could create a object of some class if i have the name of the class
in a NSString.
I know this is possible in other languages like ActionScript, C# and PHP...

Something like this:

```
NSString *className = @"AwesomeViewController";
UIViewController *object = [[className alloc] initWithNibName:className bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Classes are first-class objects in Objective-C too. You can get the class object from an NSString with the [NSClassFromString function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring?language=objc).

```
[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init...]
```

Comment: and the other way around is: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([obj class]));

Comment: Is it a weak response?

Comment: Is there a way to declare a variable using NSString too? I mean if in original poster's post, I don't want to write `UIViewController` in `UIViewController *object` but declare it base on NSString. Would that be possible?

Comment: You can just use `id` @huggie. Since the compiler won't know the class, you will get the same result.