# Looping over similarly named UI elements - maybe by getting a variable from its name?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've added a number of labels to a view using Interface Builder. I've also got an array of values I want to display.

Is there a better way to set the labels than using this code:

```
lblTotal1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Seconds", (int) round(fTimeTotal[1])];
lblTotal2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Seconds", (int) round(fTimeTotal[2])];
lblTotal3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Seconds", (int) round(fTimeTotal[3])];
lblTotal4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Seconds", (int) round(fTimeTotal[4])];
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    lblTotal[i].text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i Seconds", (int) round(fTimeTotal[i])];
}
```

But I have to be able to get a variable from it's name. How can I do this?

Comment: use nsstring stringfromclass to form the class name using variables.. hope that helps will add a more detailed comment in abit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951828/create-object-from-nsstring-of-class-name-in-objective-c

heres a good answer. cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable name from string in obj-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164860/variable-name-from-string-in-obj-c)

Comment: Josh, the question you mention sounds similar to my issue, but it does not apply to my issue of getting a bunch of UI elements in a collection. I've changed the title of the question to reflect my intentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook our IBOutlets together in an IBOutletCollection in IB (select a bunch and drag them to the source code together; it should offer to make a collection). While an IBOutletCollection is technically an ordered list (array), it is in fact randomly ordered.

Once you've hooked all your IBOutlets together into an IBOutletCollection, you'll still need to know which is which. You do this with `tag`, which is one of the fields you can set in IB. Once you've tagged them all, your code will be:

```
for (UILabel *label in self.labelCollection) {
  int value = (int)roundf(fTimeTotal[label.tag]);
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Seconds", value];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your variables like `lblTotal1` are properties, you can use key-value coding (KVC) to obtain them:

```
NSUInteger lblIndex = 1;
NSString *lblName = @[NSString stringWithFormat: @"lblTotal%d", lblIndex];

id label = [self valueForKey: lblName];
```

Depending on whether you are targeting iOS or OS X, the `id` in the last line could be any specific class for your label, of course.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if they're properties or not. As long as there is a method called `-labelTotal1`, the above is correct. Do note that if `lblName` does not name a method, then the above will crash, so be careful with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use self.view.subviews array to go through all subviews and check if it is UILabel, do your things.