# 4 UIButtons, 1 method to change the title?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have an app that lets the users chose one and only one button from four buttons.
the buttons are tied to one `IBAction` that takes id sender as a param. while each button has a tag.  When the user clicks on any button text on that button is changed to `@"*"` and checks for the other buttons to erase any previous selection.

I used this code.

```
selectedType = b.tag;
NSLog(@"%d", selectedType);



switch (selectedType) {
    case 1:
        [btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn4 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    case 2:
        [btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn4 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    case 3:
        [btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn4 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    case 4:
        [btn1 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn3 setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

[b setTitle:@"*" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is working right straight, but is there an easier technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user is only allowed to select one button then you could store which button is currently selected and when the user selects a new button, first deselect the old button and then select the new button and update the pointer to the selected button.

```
[selectedButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // deselect the old button
self.selectedButton = sender; // update the selection
[selectedButton setTitle:@"*" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // select the new button
```

The same approach is still viable if the user is allowed to select multiple buttons though you would need to keep references to all the selected buttons.

Comment: Thanks, you gave the easiest way :)

Answer (score 1):

Store buttons in an array called ***buttonsArray*** of ***NSArray*** type

```
for(UIButton *button  in buttonsArray ) {
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[b setTitle:@"*" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have not tested it, but I think this should work.
I think David's(David Rönnqvist) approach is better.

Comment: your way should work, but i think looping is not necessary. and yes Davids approach works very well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can either use NSClassFromString(className) to dynamically produce your button classes which you can set their titles

or you could use IBOutlet collections, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361856/looping-over-similarly-named-ui-elements-maybe-by-getting-a-variable-from-its#comment11820882_9361856) for some examples

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
[btn1 setTitle:(1 == selectedType) ? [btn1 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] : @"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn2 setTitle:(2 == selectedType) ? [btn2 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] : @"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn3 setTitle:(3 == selectedType) ? [btn3 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] : @"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn4 setTitle:(4 == selectedType) ? [btn4 titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] : @"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: your way works fine, but i found David's approach less to code. thanks