# Push to UIViewController dynamically

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I am a newbie in iPhone application development.

I am developing an iPad application. It contains a menu bar on top, clicking on which retrieves a sub view. The sub view consists of UIPickerView. Upon selecting a row from UIPickerView, navigates to another UIViewController.

The UIPickerView methods are written in a separate class (As this functionality comes throughout the app, I made it a general one). So,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

will not work for me!

I was able to get the name of the class to be pushed (It changes according to the selection made). Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks In Advance :-)

Comment: How is you your UIPickerView being displayed? Is it a modal? Is it a UIPopoverController?

Comment: I am just adding a sub view... [self.view addSubView:view];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you really want is to create an object from a classname

The simple answer is

```
[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init...]
```

For a more thorough answer you should look at [Create object from NSString of class name in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951828/create-object-from-nsstring-of-class-name-in-objective-c)

Comment: UIViewController *controller = [[NSClassFromString(string_that_holdes_ClassName) alloc] init]; Am I correct?? Correct me if I am wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate method (delegate methods allows communication between objects) to implement this scenario

For example in your UIPicker(.h) class define a delegate protocol as follows

```
@protocol pickerProtocol;

@interface MyPicker : NSObject {

    id <pickerProtocol> pickerDelegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) id <pickerProtocol> pickerDelegate;

@end

@protocol pickerProtocol

- (void) pushViewController;
@end
```

And call this delegate method when selecting a row from UIPickerView

```
[pickerDelegate pushViewController];
```

Then in all view controller that uses picker write the implementation of the delegate method

```
- (void) pushViewController {
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
}
```

dont for get to set the delegate as follows

```
MyPicker *picker = [MyPicker alloc]init];
picker.pickerDelegate = self;
```